# How to catch a postmessage sent to a parent element using WKScriptMessageHandler?

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I'm loading an URL in WKWebView that is sending a postmessage to a parent element:

```
window.parent.test.postMessage('A message')
```

I'm implementing WKScriptMessageHandler and trying to get that message using userController(didReceiveMessage) but it's never being called:

```
func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
    if(message.name == "test") {
        print("JavaScript is sending a message \(message.body)")
    }
}
```

I think it's because the postmessage is being sent to a parent element and I'm loading the web view directly without loading the parent element (I don't have access to the parent element). There's any way to capture the message from parent without loading that parent on my WKWebView?

Answer (score 0):

Use in javascript:

```
webkit.messageHandlers.yourCustomName.postMessage(...)
```

Inside a swift:

```
webKitViewController = segue.destination as? CustomViewControllerWithWebView

if let userContentController = webKitViewController?.webView?.configuration.userContentController {
    userContentController.add(self, name: "yourCustomName")
```

Make an extension of self:

```
extension MyController: WKScriptMessageHandler
{
    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        print("received message:\n\(message.body)")
    }
}
```

If you cant edit the javascript, wait for didload event on webview, and load the string with the javascipt that will override test postMessage function. So it will be redirected to your webkit handler.

```
webView.evaluateJavascript("window.parent.test.postMessage = function(message) {
  webkit.messageHandlers.yourCustomName.postMessage(message)}")
```

Comment: I don't have access to edit the web page. Only the URL :/

Comment: I have updated my answer. See how to override postMessage function.